# Detect which scripts are using old interpreters

Tags: scripting, lsof, incrond

I have a few Debian machines with some nearly-orphaned script interpreters, for example `/bin/bash3` and `/usr/bin/perl510`. How can I detect those scripts that still have the aforementioned interpreters in their shebang line?

```
#!/bin/bash3
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/perl510
```

Recursively searching through the filesystem is not really a viable option. Renaming the interpreters to make the scripts fail is also not in the cards.

What I succeeded in was using `incrond` for root with `IN_OPEN` to detect the *usage* of these old interpreters. From there I called a simple shell script to find out more, but the `PPID` is that of incrond. Both `fuser` and `lsof` didn't return anything.

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG=/tmp/icc.log
echo "PID  is $$"       >> ${LOG}
echo "PPID is ${PPID}"  >> ${LOG}
echo "\$1 is ${1}"      >> ${LOG}

echo "fuser ${1}"       >> ${LOG}
fuser ${1}              >> ${LOG}
echo                    >> ${LOG}

echo "lsof ${1}"        >> ${LOG}
lsof ${1}               >> ${LOG}
echo                    >> ${LOG}
```

Comment: I'd be worried about filtering simply based on `#!` string. What if a script internally invokes perl510? Or the `#!` line isn't in a format you'd guess (for example, someone's smart and uses the more portable `#!/usr/bin/env perl5`?

Comment: I suppose my main question would be, why do you want to know? Are those interpreters really taking up so much space that you need to get rid of them? If the versions are backwards-compatible, I'd recommend just changing the regular file to a symbolic link (or a hard link to the main version would work, I suppose. But it probably wouldn't be updated as part of normal system updates).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a wrapper script like so:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "`date` `whoami` $0 $*" >> /tmp/bash3_use.log

/bin/bash3.bin "$@"
```

Then rename bash3 to bash3.bin and name this script "/bin/bash3"

You may need to log more information, e.g., the working directory.